# backend error not showing immediately Angular

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm trying to show a backend error into a message box when users try to search for a patient in the database. The message body appears immediately when I get the error (no patient found error), however the message itself doesn't show unless the search button is clicked twice.

this is the backend

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  
  
  const filter = handleQueryFilter(req.query.filter)
  const sort = handleQuerySort(req.query.sort)

  const dataDisplayed = handleQueryProjection(req.query.data)


    let patients = await Patient.find(filter,dataDisplayed).sort(sort);
    return Object.entries(patients).length === 0 ? res.status(404).json(`Sory we could not find what you are looking for`) : res.json(patients)
    
})
```

html:

```
<div class="message" *ngIf="errorNoResultPage">
        <div class="msgBody">
            <i *ngIf="errorNoResultPage"  class='bx bx-tired'></i>
            <p *ngIf="errorNoResultPage" >{{message}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

ts:

```
onSearch(search:any){

let p = this.patientList.filter(p=>p.name.toLocaleLowerCase() == this.searchVlaue.toLocaleLowerCase())
this.errorNoResult(p)

}

errorNoResult(patient:any){

if(patient=== undefined){

this.errorNoResultPage= true
}

else{

    if(Object(patient).length <=0){ 
        this.patientList=[]; 
        this.errorNoResultPage=true
        this.PatientService.getPatients().subscribe(res=> console.log(res),err => {
            console.log(err);
            this.message = err; 
        });
    }

    else{
        this.errorNoResultPage = false
    }
}
```

and this is my service file:

```
getPatients(): Observable<Patient[]> {
      
      this.showNoResult = false

      var filterPram = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams['filter'] ;
      var sortPram =  this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams['sort'];

      var queryParams:  Params = {sort:sortPram ,filter:filterPram };

      console.log(queryParams);

      return this.http.get<Patient[]>(`${this.dataUri}`,
      {
        params:
        queryParams
      }).pipe(catchError(this.handleError))

}
```

**Edit:**
when I console log the error it appears immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out what is the issue with my code.

In the service file I am looking for query params to do the filtering and the sorting.

So in the ts I have to set the query params before checking for any errors return from the service file.

I just added `.then(()=>this.errorNoResult(p))` to the router navigation like this:

```
this._router.navigate(['/dashboard','patients'],{queryParams:{
      filter : this.queryParams,
      sort:sortPram
      }} ).then(()=>this.errorNoResult(p))
```